# Weird execution of ruby/git executables in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

Something strange has happened. I can't run some command line executables in Windows anymore.

Steps:

- Open `cmd`
- Run an executable, such as `ruby -v` or `git -h`

When I do that, a new command prompt opens, running that command (I think, it's too fast to see), and instantly closes again.

I've managed to print screen the new command prompt, and it shows that it's running inside this path:
`C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\3582-490`

Inside this folder, is the executable I'm tring to run.
If I run `ruby`, then ruby.exe is in there.
If I run `git`, then git.exe is in there.
And it's always emptying the folder in between, so there is always just one .exe file

Comment: It's only some console programs that do this?  Not all of them?

Comment: Anti Virus time!

Comment: Wow, you are actually correct. Haven't had a virus in YEARS :) Thanks.